# Unable to install Nagios agent on CentOS7

Tags: nagios, centos7

When I try to install the agent downloaded from (http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/agents/linux-nrpe-agent.tar.gz) I get a firewalld error. The only solutions I can find is to enable the firewall but I do not want to.

2nd, I tried this command "c*at /dev/null > 4-firewall*". But the installer also came back with an error "*The script that failed was: './A-subcomponents'*"

Is there a workaround?

```
    ============================
Nagios Linux Agent Installer
============================

This script will install the Nagios Linux Agent by executing all necessary
sub-scripts.

IMPORTANT: This script should only be used on a clean installed system:

RedHat Enterprise, CentOS, Fedora, or Oracle
OpenSUSE or SUSE Enterprise
Ubuntu or Debian

Do NOT use this on a system running any other distro or that
does not allow additional package installation.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Proceeding with installation...
Running './0-repos'...
Configuring Repos...
epel-release RPM installed OK
Repos configured OK
RESULT=0
Running './1-prereqs'...
Installing prerequisites...
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk
* epel: epel.besthosting.ua
* extras: centos.hyve.com
* rpmforge: apt.sw.be
* updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
Package autoconf-2.69-11.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-2.17-78.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libmcrypt-devel-2.5.8-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.82-21.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1penssl-devel-1.0.1e-42.el7.9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package sudo-1.8.6p7-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package sysstat-10.1.5-7.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 2:xinetd-2.3.15-12.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package bc-1.06.95-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
Prerequisites installed OK
RESULT=0
Running './2-usersgroups'...
Adding users and groups...
useradd: user 'nagios' already exists
groupadd: group 'nagios' already exists
useradd: user 'nagios' already exists
groupadd: group 'nagcmd' already exists
Users and groups added OK
RESULT=0
Running './3-services'...
/etc/services updated
RESULT=0
Running './4-firewall'...
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.
FirewallD is not running
RESULT=252

===================
INSTALLATION ERROR!
===================
Installation step failed - exiting.
Check for error messages in the install log (install.log).

If you require assistance in resolving the issue, please include install.log
in your communications with Nagios XI technical support.

The script that failed was: './4-firewall'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same folder that contains `fullinstall`, try creating an empty `installed.firewall` file by executing:

```
touch installed.firewall
```

Then try re-running

```
./fullinstall
```

This is based on line 12 of `4-firewall`:

> ```
> # Was this step already completed?
> if [ -f installed.firewall ]; then
>     echo "Firewall rules already configured - skipping."
>     exit 0
> fi
> ```

If a file named `installed.firewall` exists in that directory, the firewall configuration step should get skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can enable firewalld on your server with the following command.

To enable firewalld,

```
systemctl enable firewalld
```

To start firewalld

```
systemctl start firewalld
```

To check the status of firewalld

```
systemctl status firewalld
```